# Hover off on font-size and background-size

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to realise a nice `Hover Off effect` using CSS. There is a pretty good example [here](http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/), but I can't reproduce this with the properties `background-size` and `font-size`.

The effect is simply to zoom in the image and the text on mouse over and come back to the original state on hover off but in a clean way (using -webkit-transition). This code fails:

```
.nice a {
    background:  url(../my_image.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 37px;
    font-size: 12px;

    /* HOVER OFF */
    -webkit-transition: background-size 2s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 2s;
}

.nice a:hover{
    background: url(../my_image.png) no-repeat ;
    background-size: 43px 39px;
    font-size: 13px;

    /* HOVER ON */
    -webkit-transition: background-size 2s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 2s;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think** the problem, with the code you provided, is there aren't enough 'steps' or 'keyframes' for the animation to run smoothly.

See this demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3763579. 
The box using your properties[one on the right], has 2 seconds on the clock to animate just one or two pixels, so there'd be an apparent delay before the artifacts *jump* to the next pixel. Same with animating back to place, hence the choppy, un-smooth transition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform:scale(value);`

[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/GkRhM/)

```
.nice a {
    font-size: 12px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin:top left;
}

.nice a:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/xUsDU/4/)

and the tutorial to know more about [background](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)

This is another way to do it with transforms.

```
.nice a { -webkit-transition: font-size .2s ease-in-out; }
.nice a:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); }
```

example with key frames(drawback is not all the time hover, it won't stay).

```
@-webkit-keyframes  scalar{
    from{
         background-size: 40px 37px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
to{
    background-size: 103px 79px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
}

.nice2 a{
    background:  skyblue;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract");
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 37px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color:white;
}
.nice2 a:hover{
    -webkit-animation: scalar 1s;
}
​
```

upadated demo with [keyframes](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/xUsDU/5/)

we have seen Three ways to do it. lets decide which best for it.

1. **Transitions** which gives smooth and nice appearance.
2. **Transforms** which blurs while growing content.
3. **Keyframes** which leads to high end but...

Choice is yours!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, this works:

```
/* HOVER OFF */
-webkit-transition-property: background-size, font-size;
o-transition-property: background-size, font-size;
-moz-transition-property: background-size, font-size;
transition-property: background-size, font-size;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```